# Change variable name in multiple lines in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So, I have some code for a Rect variable `mageSection`:

[image]

And I'd like to copy the same code for a different variable `warriorSection`. To achieve this:

[image]

So I'd like to know if there is a visual studio shortcut for allow you to change variable name in multiple line in visual studio without refactoring the whole variable name.i.e. I don't have to manually change those names from `mageSection` to `warriorSection`for these 4 lines.

It is a question about shortcut in visual studio rather than writing functions, as I'd like to know the shortcut for this. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste the section of code.

Now select the pasted code and hit Ctrl-H to bring up the Quick Replace dialog.

In the top box, type "mageSection".
In the bottom box, type "warriorSection".

Hit Enter and it will find the first occurrence and replace it.
Hit Enter three more times...done.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed! :D

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you should be able to hold down alt while clicking into multiple lines and change them all at once. Then hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit multiline editing.